# Can anyone point me to a good tutorial for Microsoft Sync Framework v2?

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

I found a great walk-through for Sync Framework here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726010.aspx

But, it is using Sync Framework version 1. I would like to use version 2 of the Sync Framework, as it appears to be much simpler to implement. But, I can't find a single tutorial on it. I have been looking for a while, and I am usually pretty good at finding obscure stuff when I need it. Can someone point me to a good walk-through for version 2 of Sync Framework, similar to the one I reference above?

Thanks for whatever you can provide.

Comment: This is better suited for www.programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the tutorial you referenced above should still apply to either 2.0 or 2.1 as the SqlCeClientSyncProvider/DbServerSyncProvider (commonly referred to as offline providers) hasnt really changed that much from v1.

if you're not synchronizing devices, you might want to look at the newer SqlCeSyncProvider/SqlSyncProvider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902853(v=SQL.110).aspx

likewise, these tutorials are actually included in the documentation that get's installed when you install Sync Framework